# What characters should and should not be included (or should be escaped) in HTTP_REFERERs?

Tags: mod-rewrite, escaping, character, delimiter, http-referer

I wanted to update my .htaccess file with some new referral rewrites and found a good list in GitHub https://gist.github.com/raniajal/e6733427207de2677616#file-htaccess-txt-L72.

I had a mixed format of ones I'd found elsewhere with escaped hyphens and non-escaped hyphens; slashes at the end of .com, .org, .net, .ga, .ru, etc. and some without the ending slash such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*\.social\-buttons\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} free-share-buttons\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*yapoga\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*seoanalyses\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*savetubevideo\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*semalt\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 4webmasters\.org/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 7makemoneyonline\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 100dollars-seo\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} addons\.mozilla\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} o\-o\-6\-o\-o\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} youporn-forum\.ga/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} непереводимая\.рф/ [NC]
```

I noticed that the list in GitHub did not have the ending slashes and had updated notation to allow for https and my existing ones didn't so I updated my list to use that. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*o-o-6-o-o\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*slftsdybbg\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*social-buttons\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*socialseet\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*trafficmonetize\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*video--production\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*videos-for-your-business\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*vodkoved\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*www1\.social-buttons\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*ykecwqlixx\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*youporn-forum\.ga [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} forum\.topic65882328\.darodar\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:\/\/([^.]+\.)*непереводимая\.рф [NC]
```

But now I am getting 500 Server Error and the Error log says

> RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

The file is UTF-8 and I don't see any excess spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. There seems to be no difference in the results of the two examples. I re-re-re-read my list of HTTP_REFERER items and discovered two that caused the problem.
One in the middle of the list had only [NC] so I changed that to [NC,OR].
One was missing the [NC,OR] so I added that.

In a long list it is easy to skip over things that seem the same -- better proofreading was needed.
Now the .htaccess file works.